# Report Next Date in Sequence

Tags: sql

Our database keeps track of only 5 billing payments received each month. How can I write a select statement that will look, sequentially, at each payment received date and if there is a date entered to move on the the next payment, etc...then eventually come across the date with an empty field and report that date?

I've tried the following case statement but think I am on the wrong track;

```
select db.identifier,
case when recdate1 is not null then recdate1 
when recdate2 is not null then recdate2
when recdate3 is not null then recdate3 end
```

from db

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the COALESCE function for this. The COALESCE function will take n number of input fields, and return the first NOT NULL input field from left to right. In other words, if you sequence the recdate fields from recdate1 to recdate 5, it will return the first one that is NOT NULL.

Here is the code to achieve this.

```
SELECT db.identifier
        , COALESCE(recdate1, recdate2, recdate3, recdate4, recdate5) AS recdate
  FROM mytable
```

Here is a link to the COALESCE function for more information. Hope this helps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx